# How to install kernel from default ppa etc after manually installing it?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, secure-boot

I had some issues with a kernel and had to manually install 6.2 (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04).

Now whenever I boot I need to make sure that I disable secure boot and I suspect this is because I installed the kernel manually.

How can I go back to having the kernel be installed as per the ppa / software center updates instead of whatever I manually did.

EDIT

I manually downloaded the kernel from here [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2/) and installed using dpkg -i *deb

Comment: The safest way is to reverse whatever changes you made, which you've not told us. We don't know how you installed the kernel (*compiled kernel yourself, OR used `wget` to download then `dpkg` to install, OR added additional sources then `apt install`, OR other alternatives*), thus you're best asking whomever made those changes for clues. Alternatively if commands were used, your command history (`history` etc) should help you see that, or package history (`/var/log/apt/history.log` but that'll only help if you installed packages using `dpkg` or `apt` & not other ways!) etc.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect how the kernel was installed - why would I want to reverse the kernel install? I want to be using 6.2 which if I'm not mistaken is the latest for 22.04?

Comment: You installed the mainline PPA kernel using a correct method. There is no automatic way to get newer mainline PPA kernels. Mainline PPA kernels are not the same as Ubuntu release kernels. Automatic Ubuntu kernel updates via `apt update` and `apt upgrade` should continue to work properly.